# Using listings for R code with ## in rangeprefix

Tags: listings, external-files, r

In R, comments are preceded by the symbol `#`. Moreover, to avoid messing with the indentation, it's usually `##` instead of `#`. Therefore, as I want to include some R code in a LaTeX document, I am using the `listings` package with [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916439/597069). However, this gives me the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \lst@rangebegin
```

Here is the R code:

```
##--GOLL0----
GetObsLogLik <- function(data, w, mu, sigma){
  N <- nrow(data)
  S <- ncol(data)
  K <- nrow(mu)
  sum(sapply(1:N, function(i){
    log(sum(sapply(1:K, function(k){
      w[k] * dmvnorm(x=data[i,], mean=mu[k,],
                     sigma=sigma[k]^2 * diag(S))
    })))
  }))
}
##--GOLL1----
```

And here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R,
  frame=single,
  basicstyle=\small,
  rangeprefix=##--,
  rangesuffix=----,
  includerangemarker=false}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[linerange=GOLL0-GOLL1]{test.R}

\end{document}
```

The error disappears when I replace `##` by `//`. But this is not a solution as `//` are not valid in R. I also tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085664/597069) but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn’t the R source code, it’s the fact that you are using special characters (`#`) in the `\lstset` options. Try using `\#\#` instead.